# generator-kraken static module out of date?

Tags: express, kraken.js

Just getting started with KrakenJS.  After running the generator and looking at the config.json I notice it has the "static" middleware defined as:

```
    "static": {
        "module": {
            "arguments": [ "path:./.build" ]
        }
    }
```

I have two issues/questions:

1. After running **grunt build** I see the browserify output in the **/.build** folder, but when I navigate to **/js/app.js** it appears to load the file from the **/public** folder.  Shouldn't it be from the **/.build** folder?
2. With Express 4+ shouldn't this actually be **serve-static**?

I can't help but think I'm missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I guessed, I was missing something.

I dug into the kraken source a bit more and found that the core config defines the "name" property on static as "serve-static", so it is in fact correct when it merges with the config.json in my app.

The other issue I was having with loading from the incorrect folder was because inside the development.json config file the 'kraken-devtools' middleware is configured with the **copier** compiler, so when the file is requested at runtime it copies it from the **/public** folder into the **/.build** folder, overwriting the output from **grunt build**.